# Problem rolling out ADO.Net Data Service application to IIS

Tags: .net, web-services, iis, wcf-data-services

I am adding a ADO.Net Data Service lookup feature to an existing web page.  Everything works great when running from visual studio, but when I roll it out to IIS, I get the following error:

> **Request Error**
> The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.

I get this even when trying to display the default page, i.e.:

> http://server/FFLookup.svc

I have 3.5 SP1 installed on the server.

What am I missing, and which "Server Logs" is it refering to?  I can't find any further error messages.

There is nothing in the Event Viewer logs (System or Application), and nothing in the IIS logs other than the GET:

> 2008-09-10 15:20:19 10.7.131.71 GET /FFLookup.svc - 8082 - 10.7.131.86 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+5.1;+en-US)+AppleWebKit/525.13+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/0.2.149.29+Safari/525.13 401 2 2148074254

There is no stack trace returned.  The only response I get is the "Request Error" as noted above.

Thanks

Patrick

Comment: Can you run IIS manager (Run > inetmgr) and right click the service file. Click Browse. you might get more error details if you try with localhost. Also note the url in the Browser. Maybe the website is configured for a different port.

Answer (score 42):

In order to verbosely display the errors resulting from your data service you can place the following tag above your dataservice definition:

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
```

This will then display the error in your browser window as well as a stack trace.

In addition to this dataservices throws all exceptions to the HandleException method so if you implement this method on your dataservice class you can put a break point on it and see the exception:

```
protected override void HandleException(HandleExceptionArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    e.UseVerboseErrors = true;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Well I found the "Server Logs" mentioned in the error above.

You need to turn on tracing in the web.config file by adding the following tags:

```
    <system.diagnostics>
      <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing" >
            <listeners>
                <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener"/>
            </listeners>
        </source>

        <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose,ActivityTracing"        >
            <listeners>
                <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener"/>
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="System.Runtime.Serialization" switchValue="Verbose,ActivityTracing">
            <listeners>
                <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener"/>
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add initializeData="App_tracelog.svclog"   
                        type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
                        name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp"/>
    </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
```

This will create a file called app_tracelog.svclog in your website directory.

You then use the SvcTraceViewer.exe utility to view this file.  The viewer does a good job of highlighting the errors (along with lots of other information about the communications).

**Beware: The log file created with the above parameters grows very quickly.  Only turn it on during debuging!**

In this particular case, the problem ended up being the incorrect version of OraDirect.Net, our Oracle Data Provider.  The version we were using did not support 3.5 SP1.

Comment: Did it help to solve your problem. Would be great if you can share your findings.

Answer (score 0):

For me the error was caused by two methods having the same name (unintended overloading).

> Overloading is not supported but type 'abc' has an overloaded method 'Void SubmitCart(System.String, Int32)'.

I found out by running the service in debug mode.