# ADO.NET Data Services Entity Framework request error when property setter is internal

Tags: entity-framework, service, ado.net

I receive an error message when exposing an ADO.NET Data Service using an Entity Framework data model that contains an entity (called "Case") with an internal setter on a property. If I modify the setter to be public (using the entity designer), the data services works fine.

I don’t need the entity "Case" exposed in the data service, so I tried to limit which entities are exposed using SetEntitySetAccessRule. This didn’t work, and service end point fails with the same error.

```
public static void InitializeService(IDataServiceConfiguration config)
{
    config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("User", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
}
```

The error message is reported in a browser when the .svc endpoint is called. It is very generic, and reads “Request Error. The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.” Unfortunately, there are no entries in the System and Application event logs.

I found this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54380/problem-rolling-out-adonet-data-service-application-to-iis) that shows how to configure tracing on the service. After doing so, the following NullReferenceExceptoin error was reported in the trace log.

Does anyone know how to avoid this exception when including an entity with an internal setter?

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
<EventID>131076</EventID>
<Type>3</Type>
<SubType Name="Error">0</SubType>
<Level>2</Level>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2008-11-05T22:30:44.1523578Z" />
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
<Correlation ActivityID="{da77ee97-960f-4275-a5e7-a181c0b024b1}" />
<Execution ProcessName="WebDev.WebServer" ProcessID="6388" ThreadID="8" />
<Channel />
<Computer>MOTOJIM</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceHandledException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Handling an exception.</Description>
<AppDomain>685a2910-19-128703978432492675</AppDomain>
<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.Data.Services.Providers.ObjectContextServiceProvider.PopulateMemberMetadata(ResourceType resourceType, MetadataWorkspace workspace, IDictionary`2 entitySets, IDictionary`2 knownTypes)
at System.Data.Services.Providers.ObjectContextServiceProvider.PopulateMetadata(IDictionary`2 knownTypes, IDictionary`2 entitySets)
at System.Data.Services.Providers.BaseServiceProvider.PopulateMetadata()
at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateProvider(Type dataServiceType, Object dataSourceInstance, DataServiceConfiguration&amp; configuration)
at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.EnsureProviderAndConfigForRequest()
at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.ProcessRequestForMessage(Stream messageBody)
at SyncInvokeProcessRequestForMessage(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp; outputs)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Data.Services.Providers.ObjectContextServiceProvider.PopulateMemberMetadata(ResourceType resourceType, MetadataWorkspace workspace, IDictionary`2 entitySets, IDictionary`2 knownTypes)
   at System.Data.Services.Providers.ObjectContextServiceProvider.PopulateMetadata(IDictionary`2 knownTypes, IDictionary`2 entitySets)
   at System.Data.Services.Providers.BaseServiceProvider.PopulateMetadata()
   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateProvider(Type dataServiceType, Object dataSourceInstance, DataServiceConfiguration&amp; configuration)
   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.EnsureProviderAndConfigForRequest()
   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.ProcessRequestForMessage(Stream messageBody)
   at SyncInvokeProcessRequestForMessage(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp; outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</ExceptionString>
</Exception>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into a similar issue, and the fix in my case was changinghe the name of the EntitySetAccessRule to "*", like this:

```
public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
{
  config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
  config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and it was caused by passing the wrong class to DataService. You need to pass the data entities class of the data model.

```
public class WebDataService : DataService< DataModel.DataEntities >
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the solution turned out to be very simple: although my table name and the generated entity object is the singular "Order", I need to refer to it in this context as "Orders".  Still getting my head around that. just EDM standard.

```
config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Orders", EntitySetRights.All);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issue caused by EF6.

According to [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2013/10/02/using-wcf-data-services-5-6-0-with-entity-framework-6.aspx) changing

```
public class WebDataService : DataService< DataModel.DataEntities >
```

to

```
public class WebDataService : EntityFrameworkDataService< DataModel.DataEntities >
```

should help