# WCF test client error when using Visual Studio 2017 community edition

Tags: c#, wcf, service-model

I have been experiencing this issue when trying to get my WCF service running. Any help will be highly appreciated.

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'.

```
See server logs for more details. 
The exception stack trace is:
at System.Data.Services.Providers.ObjectContextServiceProvider.PopulateMetadata(ProviderMetadataCacheItem metadataCacheItem) 
at System.Data.Services.Providers.BaseServiceProvider.LoadMetadata(Boolean skipServiceOperations) 
at System.Data.Services.Providers.EntityFrameworkDataService`1.CreateInternalProvider(Object dataSourceInstance) 
at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateMetadataAndQueryProviders(IDataServiceMetadataProvider& metadataProviderInstance, IDataServiceQueryProvider& queryProviderInstance, Object& dataSourceInstance, Boolean& isInternallyCreatedProvider) 
at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateProvider() 
at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest() 
at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.ProcessRequestForMessage(Stream messageBody) at SyncInvokeProcessRequestForMessage(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Comment: Informations are too few... The problem seems due to EntityFrameworkDataService... did you check all connection string to database and their reacheability (ie. for authentication service etc...)

Comment: See that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266927/ado-net-data-services-entity-framework-request-error-when-property-setter-is-int

Comment: @GianlucaConte I had a look at the EntityFrameworkDataService and the connectionstring in the solution and all seems to be well. Also had a look at the provided link and followed the suggestions there as well, but to no avail...

Comment: I created the wcf service after I had created my mvc application and the reason for its creation was so that I caould be able to get my application to work with my xamarin.android application, but it seems I only made things worse...